# Stop slf4j messages from printing in java

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I have the below code and donot want these log messages to be printed.I also want to stop log messages from other libraries in the same project to be printed.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Main{


public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Logger slf4jLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
    slf4jLogger.info("im printing info");
    slf4jLogger.error("printing error");
}
```

I have log4j.properties under src/test/resources also added in classpath.
log4j.properties is as follows

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
log4j.logger.main=OFF
```

I want to stop these logs from printing to console.
But its not working and printing the logs.
Is it something which i am missing?

Comment: is the problem you are having that it is logging, or that it is logging to the prompt? for me, personally, you shouldn't log to the prompt, rather to a log file that can be checked afterwards.

Comment: what exactly you want ? are you want to stop printing the log completly or only want to stop to print on console ?

Comment: I want to stop it printing to the console.

Comment: Also i will be exporting this project as a jar and want to prevent logs from printing on command line.

Comment: so configure a log file, instead of the prompt

Comment: Can you please tell me how can all these slf4j messages be routed to a file

Comment: I was able to stop all apache common loggings logs by using this property     System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log","org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

Comment: I assume you have included the SLF4J bridge for Log4J on your classpath right?

Comment: I have slf4j-api.jar and log4j-slf4j-impl.jar in my maven dependencies. log4j.properties is added on classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using Log4J 2, which according to the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) requires, in the absence of a `log4j.configurationFile` system property, the configuration file be named `log4j2.properties`, not `log4j.properties` as you have.

As the docs say:

> If no configuration file could be located the DefaultConfiguration
>   will be used. This will cause logging output to go to the console.

It's also odd that you've got the configuration file in `/src/test/resources` rather than `/src/main/resources`, so depending how you think you've got the configuration file onto the classpath, this might also cause a problem.

Comment: I was using Log4j 2 and had to change the properties file to Lo4j2.xml.